# Applying Rouche's Theorem

Tags: complex-analysis

For a complex polynomial: $F(z) = z^8+5z^7-z^4+2$, how many roots does it have in the disk $|z|\lt 1$?
I want to apply Rouche's Theorem. So let $f(z)=5z^7$. Then $|F(z)-f(z)|=|z^8-z^4+2| \le |z^8|+|-z^4|+|2|$. At $|z|=1$, $1 + 1 + 2 = 4 < 5 = |f(z)|$  which implies F(z) has 7 roots in $|z|<1$. Does anyone agree?

What about the number of roots in $4<|z|<6$? There are $8$ in $|z|<6$ by similar argument and $7$ in $|z|<4$ by the same argument for $|z|<1$. So there is $1$ root in $4<|z|<6$.

Comment: Looks good to me. There is just a typo, you should have written "at $|z|=1$". Besides, $F$ has $7$ roots in $\mathbb{D}$ counting with multiplicity.

Comment: How do we check how many roots are on the boundary of a disk? Suppose I was check for $4 < |z|< 6$ instead? Well, I need to see if there are roots on $|z|=4$ yes?

Comment: You don't need to count the roots on the boundary. Rouché's theorem states that if $f_1,f_2$ are holomorphic on a open neighborhood of $\overline{\mathbb{D}(z_0,r)}$ and if $|f_1-f_2|<|f_1|$ on $\partial\mathbb{D}(z_0,r)$, then $f_1$ and $f_2$ have the same numbers of zeros counting with multiplicity on $\mathbb{D}(z_0,r)$.